# ActiveAdmin batch_action template error and no update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My ActiveAdmin registered model has an "active" boolean field.  I want to include a batch action to "activate" multiple records at once.

I am trying to follow the instructions at:

http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html

for doing a custom batch action and I am having two problems.

I have this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Venue do

  batch_action :deactivate do |selection|
    Venue.find(selection).each do |v|
      v.active = false
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to activate something I get a template not found error.  It is looking for a "batch_action" template.  I didn't see anything in that doc about needing to also add a template.  If I add a template with that name the error goes away and it displays the template...this is of course not what I want.  I want it to just redisplay the index.

In either case (with or without a template in place), the model is not being updated.  I can see in the log where it just does a select for the selected records and does nothing else.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got rid of the issues by doing the following:

```
batch_action :activate do |selection|
  Venue.find(selection).each do |v|
    v.active = true
    v.save
  end
  redirect_to :back  #this ensures any current filter stays active
end
```

The 'save' part seems obvious but the example in the docs threw me off on my first attempt.  It seems like this would be a more relevant example for the docs.